# Tradingview strategy based on 1st 15minute cand;e

Tags: pine-script, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to write a strategy that if the first 15 minute candle prints red, it'll enter a short position, and then close the position at 10:30am. I'm really struggling to get it to understand the timeframe on the current day. Any suggestions? This is what I got so far.

```
FromMonth       = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Month", minval = 1)
testPeriodStart = timestamp(hour=9, minute=45)

testPeriodStop = timestamp(hour=10, minute=30)

short= open > close
stop= open < close

if time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=short)
strategy.close("Short", when=stop)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `input.session` instead of comparing timestamps.
2. `when` parameter of the `strategy.entry()` inside `if` statement is rather incorrect, use only `if` statement or only `when` parameter.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

i_sess = input.session("0945-1030", "Session")
inSession = time(timeframe.period, i_sess)

short = open > close
stop = open < close

if inSession and short
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    
if not inSession or stop
    strategy.close("Short")
```